# Spring boot @Scheduled Annotation not working when deploying on Tomcat

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-boot

I have a `@Scheduled` method which runs without a problem when I build my Spring Boot application as jar using the embedded tomcat.
However, when I do the modifications described here ( https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html ), my rest services are deployed but the `@Scheduled` methods don't seem to be executing.

Comment: Need more information about your project. Are you using Maven/Gradle? Tomcat version, Spring boot version, Spring version, Java version, snippet of configuration would all help. I was able to put together a simple Spring Boot app that works fine with `@Scheduled` annotations when deployed to Tomcat 8.

Comment: Add some code/configuration you are using.